# Issue: Invalid or incomplete login credentials for Google login

Tags: android, google-play-console

I recently uploaded an app to play console soon after I received a mail sayin "Issue: Invalid or incomplete login credentials". I searched for solutions and found that i neto add login details to app access in play console but the problem is my app has only google sign in. How to fix?

In the additional instructions box I said click on google sign in button thn select google account and it vl log you in but still rejected.